# How to make parallel call in Java 8

Tags: java, parallel-processing, patch

How can I make parallel calls in Java 8?

I need to call an endpoint by sending the data via a patch to be updated. Since there is so much data, I don't want to do a `forEach()` for each one, but I want to do it in parallel and continue the process only when all parallel calls have answered.
Can you help me?

Comment: E.g. using the streaming api with parallelStream() would be a way, there are a number of [possibilities](https://www.google.com/search?q=parallel+http+java). Didn't down vote myself, but the one who did may justify it with "lack of research for SO standards" or so.

Comment: In addition to the `stream support` framework supporting parallel processing you should read up on concurrency (using Threads) in Java.  There are many classes which are designed to support concurrency.  Probably  one of the best is `ForkJoin`

Comment: [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `CompletableFuture` API. Consider the next example

```
// the initial data
ArrayList<String> data = ...;

// submit a call for each element separately
CompletableFuture[] futures = data.stream()
         .map(datum -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
              // do call
          }))
          .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

// wait for all the calls to finish
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
```

Future is an abstraction, which means result of asynchronous computation. It can either be finished and have a result or be processing. `allOf` methods waits for completion of all the created futures.

In the above example each call will be made in a separate thread of a thread pool (default is ForkJoinPool). However, if number of elements in the dataset is big enough, I would suggest to split in multiple groups and process requests sequentially within one group.

Let's say you have 16 worker threads and consequently 16 groups. Number of elements is 100. You have to distribute these 100 elements across these 16 workers and process them sequentially inside each worker.

If the matter is HTTP call, you can also consider asynchronous HTTP clients

Comment: To make my code based on the above sample work, I had add .join(): 
  CompletableFuture.allOf().join()